# How do i get the login status of a user in AD with LDAP

Tags: ldap

Is it possible to ask the Active Directies if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see their last login time, which would answer if they have EVER logged in, but not that I am aware of, if they are currently logged in.

Comment: Yes as I can call LastLoginOn, i would like something that could give me IsCurrentlyLoggedIn, or somesort of workaround would be fine too.

Comment: Problem is, what does logged in mean, which is why each directory service has a different definition, if at all.  What does it mean that they have now logged out?  What timeout interval?  Etc?  It seems simple, but it is not quite so simple in the real world.

Comment: You were right. It's not possible, i founded the answer in another question on stakcoverflow. thx for the help.